# How to get the value of the input fields and store it in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

The code is working but I'am getting all the values in a single time , what I want is getting the value when the remove button is click and then store those values in an array. Please Help me I'm kinda stuck in this. Totally new to javascript. Tried searching on google but no luck at all.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="">
          <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">
            <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

        <!-- Copy Fields-These are the fields which we get through jquery and then add after the above input,-->
        <div class="copy-fields hide">
          <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
            <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      /* here first get the contents of the div with name class copy-fields and add it to after "after-add-more" div class. */
      $(".add-more").click(function() {
        var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
        $(".after-add-more").after(html);
      });

      /* here it will remove the current value of the remove button which has been pressed */
      $("body").on("click", ".remove", function() {
        var values = $(this).val();
        alert(values);
        $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you want to get the active values. is this what your question?

Comment: unable to understand what you are asking

Comment: Yes and via the remove button that is beside the input field. However when I try to do this I'm getting all the values in the dynamically added input fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var arrays = [];

$(".add-more").click(function(){ 
   var html = $(".copy-fields").html();
   $(".after-add-more").after(html);
});

$("body").on("click",".remove",function(){
    var value = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input').val();   
    arrays.push(value);
    console.log($(this).closest('.input-group').find('input').val());
    console.log("arrays: ", arrays)
    $(this).parents(".control-group").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"> 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <form action="" >

    <div class="input-group control-group after-add-more">


           <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
                  <div class="input-group-btn"> 
                    <button class="btn btn-success add-more" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add</button>
                  </div>
          </div>

    </form>


    <!-- Copy Fields-These are the fields which we get through jquery and then add after the above input,-->
    <div class="copy-fields hide">
      <div class="control-group input-group" style="margin-top:10px">
        <input type="text" name="addmore[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name Here">
        <div class="input-group-btn"> 
          <button class="btn btn-danger remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to be working however i want to store those values in an array how exactly can I achieve that ?

Comment: Edited codes (store in array in script) @BLuu-II 
I hope it is useful ❤️

Answer (score 0):

Basically assign `onclick` event to reset button, which gets values from text fields and e.g. `array_name.push(document.getElementByName('addmore[]').value);` and then do what do you need.